# Color histogram of a live preview

Tags: react-native, opengl-es, gpuimage, webgl2

I have been trying to a generate a color histogram from a picture (actually a live camera preview) using the GPU, hence `opengl-es`. I came across the `GPUImage` library which contains a [histogram filter](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2/blob/858b01fc2fd7d1e07a697e8dc6c3a119e4773ef1/framework/Source/Operations/Histogram.swift). I cannot use this library directly, as I am using `react-native` with Expo's `GLView` (as documented [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/gl-view.html)), and I don't want to deal with native code.

This being said, I should be able to adapt the code to use the `WebGL API` managed by `GLView`. I've been trying to do exactly this, but the histogram data retrieved only contains "black pixels".

*Defining shaders:*

```
const histogramRedSamplingVertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

in vec4 position;
out vec3 colorFactor;

void main()
{
  colorFactor = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (position.x * 0.0078125), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
}
`;
const histogramGreenSamplingVertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

in vec4 position;
out vec3 colorFactor;

void main()
{
  colorFactor = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (position.y * 0.0078125), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
}
`;
const histogramBlueSamplingVertexShaderSource = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

in vec4 position;
out vec3 colorFactor;

void main()
{
  colorFactor = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl_Position = vec4(-1.0 + (position.z * 0.0078125), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl_PointSize = 1.0;
}
`;

const histogramAccumulationFragmentShaderSource = `#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

in lowp vec3 colorFactor;
out vec4 fragColor;

const lowp float scalingFactor = 1.0 / 256.0;
void main()
{
  fragColor = vec4(colorFactor * scalingFactor, 1.0);
}`;
```

*Helper functions (for reference)*

```
createShader = (gl, type, source) => {
  var shader = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
  gl.compileShader(shader);
  var success = gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
  if (success) {
    return shader;
  }

  console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
  gl.deleteShader(shader);
};

createProgram = (gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader) => {
  var program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  gl.validateProgram(program);
  var success = gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS);
  if (success) {
    return program;
  }
  console.log(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  gl.deleteProgram(program);
};
```

*Init*

```
// width and height of the camera view.
const { width, height } = this.state;
const downsamplingFactor = 16;

const cameraTexture = (this.texture = await this.createCameraTexture());
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cameraTexture);

const cameraFramebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
const histogramFramebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();

const histogramAccumulationFragmentShader = this.createShader(gl, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, histogramAccumulationFragmentShaderSource);

const histogramRedSamplingVertexShader = this.createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, histogramRedSamplingVertexShaderSource);
const histogramRedSamplingProgram = this.createProgram(gl, histogramRedSamplingVertexShader, histogramAccumulationFragmentShader);

const histogramGreenSamplingVertexShader = this.createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, histogramGreenSamplingVertexShaderSource);
const histogramGreenSamplingProgram = this.createProgram(gl, histogramGreenSamplingVertexShader, histogramAccumulationFragmentShader);

const histogramBlueSamplingVertexShader = this.createShader(gl, gl.VERTEX_SHADER, histogramBlueSamplingVertexShaderSource);
const histogramBlueSamplingProgram = this.createProgram(gl, histogramBlueSamplingVertexShader, histogramAccumulationFragmentShader);
```

*Render loop*

```
// Binding camera texture to framebuffer
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, cameraFramebuffer);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(
  gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
  gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
  gl.TEXTURE_2D,
  cameraTexture,
  0
);

// Reading pixel data from the camera image.
const pixelData = new Uint8Array(4 * width * height);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelData);
console.log(pixelData[101]); // Logging one random pixel (yields value different from zero)

// Adapted from https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2/blob/master/framework/Source/Operations/Histogram.swift

// releaseIncomingFramebuffers
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
// activateFramebufferForRendering
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, histogramFramebuffer);
gl.viewport(0, 0, 256, 3);

// clearFramebufferWithColor
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// enableAdditiveBlending
gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_ADD);
gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE);
gl.enable(gl.BLEND);

// histogramRedSamplingProgram
gl.useProgram(histogramRedSamplingProgram);
const histogramRedPositionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(
  histogramRedSamplingProgram,
  'position'
);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
  histogramRedPositionAttributeLocation,
  4,
  gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
  0,
  (downsamplingFactor - 1) * 4,
  pixelData
);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, width * height / downsamplingFactor);

// histogramGreenSamplingProgram
gl.useProgram(histogramGreenSamplingProgram);
const histogramGreenPositionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(
  histogramGreenSamplingProgram,
  'position'
);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
  histogramGreenPositionAttributeLocation,
  4,
  gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
  0,
  (downsamplingFactor - 1) * 4,
  pixelData
);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, width * height / downsamplingFactor);

// histogramBlueSamplingProgram
gl.useProgram(histogramBlueSamplingProgram);
const histogramBluePositionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(
  histogramBlueSamplingProgram,
  'position'
);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
  histogramBluePositionAttributeLocation,
  4,
  gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
  0,
  (downsamplingFactor - 1) * 4,
  pixelData
);
gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, width * height / downsamplingFactor);

// disableBlending
gl.disable(gl.BLEND);

// End of transposition.

const histogramData = new Uint8Array(3 * 256 * 3);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 256, 3, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, histogramData);
// Try to read some pixel data, from the histogram 256x1 center line,
// these should be different from zero.
console.log([
  histogramData[256 * 3 + 120],
  histogramData[256 * 3 + 121],
  histogramData[256 * 3 + 122],
]);
```

The histogram data only contains zeroes (while the camera pixel data is valid/non-zero values). There are chances that the error is around the framebuffers; in the "model", the [framebuffer has a defined size](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage2/blob/master/framework/Source/Operations/Histogram.swift#L59), but I can't see how to transpose it. (It is also possible that the error comes from somewhere else).

Comment: @Rabbid76 Just tried it, same result `[0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: I just thought I'd pass on [this example](https://github.com/greggman/webgl-fundamentals/blob/histogram/webgl/lessons/webgl-histogram.md) that I deleted from SO ([also as a fiddle in WebGL1](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/9amgpndt/) and [WebGL2](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/vumyfknb/))